# Git clone failing with "initial ref transation called with existing refs"

Tags: git

I tried cloning my website repo and I got this error that I've never had before. I don't know if
I should still try to use my local repo if its unstable.

```
chen@chen-laptop-uwu:/media/chen/storage/development/fleepy.tv$ git clone https://github.com/flleeppyy/fleepy.tv .
Cloning into '.'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 467, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (467/467), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (282/282), done.
remote: Total 722 (delta 266), reused 358 (delta 172), pack-reused 255
Receiving objects: 100% (722/722), 30.34 MiB | 2.12 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (356/356), done.
BUG: refs/files-backend.c:2956: initial ref transaction called with existing refs
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 5):

Any Git output that begins with `BUG:` means Git has self-detected some kind of internal error.  You should report the bug, and try installing a different (newer or older) Git version to see if that can get around it.

In *this particular case*, the fact that you used `git clone <url> .` (with a literal dot) to clone into the *current* directory *might* have something to do with it.  You could try cloning into a directory that `git clone` itself makes, by leaving out the final `.`.  That's just a guess, though.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this error after trying to clone a random repo from github.

In order to fix it, I just removed the incomplete repo folder and tried to clone it again. This last time I got no error.

Comment: Deleting the folder that was created with previous git clone solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I realized that I had created a folder, which only put the related preprocessing data, with the same name to a GitHub repository.

Specifically, the folder was located in a different path from where I had cloned repository, so I didn't notice this in the beginning. After renaming the folder I had created and refreshing VSCode. I was able to successfully clone the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the directory name to be cloned in, solved the bug (for me).

```
git clone https://github.com/user/reponame <dirname>
```

Answer (score -2):

It sometimes helps to initialize the directory you're in as a Git repository.  To do that, run `git init` first.

Run this next time:

```
git init
git clone https://github.com/your-profile/your-repo.git
```

For additional details, read the documentation on cloning repos here: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Comment: Why would you run `git init` before `git clone`? Especially since the former operates on the current directory and the latter creates a new directory in the format you show?